# How to vectorize a for loop for a cell format matrix

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a matrix in cell format, each element is a cell which contains two numbers, for example if c1 be the cell with index 1, i have c1 = (k1,k2). I want to do some operation for each cell for example something like this:

```
(k1-a) + (k2-b)
```

the main operation is:

```
[(k1-a1)/(z1-a1) * (k1-a2)/(z1-a2) * ....] * [(k2-b1)/(z2-b1) * (k2-b2)/(z2-k2) * ...]
```

but i don't want to use for loop and i think do it for the whole matrix once is a faster way.
How is this possible?

Comment: Does your matrix *need* to be a cell array? If the contents are uniform, it can just be an N-dimensional matrix instead. This will make it easy to do what you're asking (efficiently).

Comment: No, because of the operation for each cell i will receive a number.

Comment: Is it an option to do `cell2mat` on your cell array?

Comment: just two numbers, they are all numbers

Comment: Sorry must have asked about `a1`, `a2` .. `b1`, `b2`.. too. Where do we get those from?

Comment: actually i have another matrix in cell format, each of their cells contains (a1,b1),(a2,b2),...

Comment: I am assuming `z` is another cell array with `z1`, `z2`, etc.?

Comment: yes, but i have them all. consider that the matrix i want to compute for each its cell the operation is A, the whole others are constant. I want to just put each cell of A in the equation and compute it

Comment: If the elements of your cell array are cell arrays, then you wouldn't be able to access them with regular brackets. Can you clarify this?

Comment: in each cell i have two number, k1 and k2

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Are these numbers in a *cell array* (the kind you access with curvy brackets) or a vector?

Comment: yes, each two numbers, k1 and k2 are in a cell, these cells together form a cell array for example n by m

Comment: In the edited code, for the second term of the first half, you have `(k1-a2)/(z1-a2)`  and for the second term of the second half you have `(k2-b2)/(z2-k2)`. `(z1-a2)` and `(z2-k2)` don't form any pattern, so could you double check those?

Answer (score 2):

One approach -

```
num2cell(reshape(sum(bsxfun(@minus,vertcat(C{:}),[a b]),2),size(C))) %%// C is input cell array
```

**Edit 1:** From all the little pieces of information I could gather of your question and comments, I am hoping this is what you need -

```
%%// **** INPUTS (Sample values taken here for demo). 
%%// Replace these with your values
AB = [{[1 0]} {[2 7]} {[2 2]} ; {[6 2]} {[7 6]} {[5 4]}]; %%// a-b cell array
c1 = {[2 3]}; %%// c1 cell array
z12 = {[4 3]}; %%// z12 cell array

%%// ***** Processing starts here
%%// Read in data into double matrices
c1mat = cell2mat(c1)
k1 = c1mat(1);
k2 = c1mat(2);

z12mat = cell2mat(z12)
z1 = z12mat(1);
z2 = z12mat(2);

ABmat = cell2mat(AB);
Amat = ABmat(:,1:2:end)
Bmat = ABmat(:,2:2:end)
Amat = Amat(:);
Bmat = Bmat(:);

%%// This is your [(k1-a1)/(z1-a1) * (k1-a2)/(z1-a2) * ....]
v1 = prod((k1-Amat)./(z1-Amat))

%%// This is your [(k2-b1)/(z2-b1) * (k2-b2)/(z2-k2) * ...]
v2 = prod((k2-Bmat)./(z2-Bmat))

%%// Final output
out = v1.*v2
```

Comment: It was an example dear Divakar for the operation, It is a little more complex. i will edit the question for more information

Comment: @user3482383 Check out **Edit 1**!

Comment: How about if c1 be a cell array for example m by n? there is also another problem, for zome z1 and z2, they are equal to Amat or Bmat so the denominator will be zeros, among Amats or Bmats i want those which are not equal to z1 and z2 (Amat~=z1 and Bmat~=z2)

Comment: Regarding `c1`, if it is of mxn size, so is it of the same size as AB cell array?

Comment: Just to clear out more confusions, could you post cell array sizes of `AB` (cell array holding a's and b's) and `z12` (cell array holding `z1` and `z2`), which should be 2x1 if it's just `z1` and `z2`?